# how to get java.io.file by using play.WS?

Tags: java, file, scala, playframework, byte

I can get `bytes` from using `Play WS` but i need `java.io.file` to upload in `AWS S3`.

```
WS.url("http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Indian%20%20Celebrities%28F%29/Yami%20Gautam/yami-gautam-27a.jpg").get().map { response =>
  val in = response.getAHCResponse.getResponseBodyAsBytes
Ok("yami")
}
```

now how i get `java.io.File`?

Comment: Write your bytes to a temp file, then upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mikesname suggests, try writing bytes to temp file and then upload. Use promises and async features of play framework. I am sure you can convert this java code to scala as part of your homework:

```
Promise<File> filePromise = WS.url("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967252/how-to-get-java-io-file-by-using-play-ws").get().map((r) -> {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    File file = File.createTempFile("file", null);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream bodyAsStream = r.getBodyAsStream();
        byte[] barr = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = bodyAsStream.read(barr)) != -1) {
            out.write(barr, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
    return file;
});

filePromise.map((file) -> {
    // Use amazon service to upload.
    return file;
});
```

Comment: getBodyAsSream() is deprecated as of PLay 2.6